# NMDS ordination interpretation from R output

Tags: r

I have conducted an NMDS analysis and have plotted the output too. However, I am unsure how to actually report the results from R. Which parts from the following output are of most importance? The graph that is produced also shows two clear groups, how are you supposed to describe these results?

```
MDS.out

Call:
metaMDS(comm = dgge2, distance = "bray") 

global Multidimensional Scaling using monoMDS

Data:     dgge2 
Distance: bray 

Dimensions: 2 
Stress:     0 
Stress type 1, weak ties
No convergent solutions - best solution after 20 tries
Scaling: centring, PC rotation, halfchange scaling 
Species: expanded scores based on ‘dgge2’
```

Answer (score 2):

The most important pieces of information are that stress=0 which means the fit is complete **and** there is still no convergence. This happens if you have six or fewer observations for two dimensions, or you have degenerate data. You should not use NMDS in these cases. Current versions of vegan will issue a warning with near zero stress. Perhaps you had an outdated version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best interpretation is just a plot of principal component. yOu can use `plot` and `text` provided by `vegan` package. Here I am creating a `ggplot2` version( to get the legend gracefully):

[image]

```
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
data(dune)
ord = metaMDS(comm = dune)
ord_spec <- scores(ord, "spec")
ord_spec <- cbind.data.frame(ord_spec,label=rownames(ord_spec))
ord_sites <- scores(ord, "sites")
ord_sites <- cbind.data.frame(ord_sites,label=rownames(ord_sites))
ggplot(data=ord_spec,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=label,col='species')) +
  geom_text(data=ord_sites,aes(label=label,col='sites'))
```